# finding an index i such that a[i] = i

Tags: c, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interview question - Search in sorted array X for index i such that X[i] = i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172580/interview-question-search-in-sorted-array-x-for-index-i-such-that-xi-i)

You are given with a sorted array of integer and the length of array. Now you have to find an index `i` such that `a(i)=i`.
I am able to do it in o(logn) if index is given but what about if index `i` is not mentioned?

Comment: If i is given, I can do it in constant time :)

Comment: i have done it using modified binary search,your solution ...

Comment: @prp how did you sort the array in O(log n) time?

Comment: mid = (low+high)/2

if [ a[mid]=mid ]
then
return mid

FindIndex_Value(array,low,mid-1)
FindIndex_Value(array,mid+1,high)

Comment: @paxdiablo & david array is already sorted...:)

Comment: @prp: This is O(n) and equivalent to the naive loop.

Comment: @prp Please update the question giving all the information. It's utterly pointless to ask a question like this and expect us to guess what you mean.

Comment: Dupe: and the wording of the original is far clearer!

Comment: It's only a dupe if there is missing info from this question (the other one had all sorts of extra snippets of info). That may be likely but it's by no means guaranteed. @prp, you should edit the question to add any information that was left out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Alexandre stated in a comment, the foreknowledge of the index means it's `O(1)`, not `O(log N)`.

And, unless there's some information you're not telling us, you need `O(n)` time to do this without that foreknowledge:

```
for x = 0 to len(a) - 1:
    if a[x] = x:
        return x
```

---

Clarification: The original question did not state that the list was sorted, that was added later. Since that makes the question a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172580/interview-question-search-in-sorted-array-x-for-index-i-such-that-xi-i), you should look to the answers there for the solution.

*This* answer will be left as is since there's no point in duplicating the others, and it's relevant for the unsorted case.

Comment: @paxdiablo you mean to say if index i is not given ,we will be doing it in o(n),am i right..

Comment: Presumably the extra information is that the array is sorted.

Comment: @prp, yes. I'm answering the "if index i is not mentioned" bit. Others have already stated that it's O(1) if you already have the index.

Comment: @David, that would be _one_ thing. Others may be upper and lower bounds, no duplicates, or any of a dozen other limitations.

Comment: @paxdiablo no duplicates I suspect.

Comment: This isn't true. There is an O(log n) algorithm in the link given in the "possible duplicate". Basically, binary search on a[i] - i. For example, say the numbers are in the range 0 to 100. If the 50th element is 55, then you know none of the elements above it fit the criteria.

*Unless duplicates are allowed, but I think you can still modify the solution and get O(logn) (EDIT: oops, didn't see it was closed as duplicate!)

Comment: @bo1024: if you examine the question history, you'll find the original question did not state that the list was sorted. That was added after this answer was posted and, since the addition made this a duplicate, I saw no reason to update the answer since the question was going to be closed and the linked question has many fine answers already. But I'll clarify, just in case someone else stumbles upon the issue.

Answer (score 1):

With the information given, you need to check values until you find a match. The worst case scenario (no match, or match found in last cell) is O(n).
If the array is already sorted you can do a binary search, which is O(log n).

Your claim is either false, or you left out some information.

Comment: -1: You can't do a standard binary search to solve this.

Comment: Correct, you can't use bsearch() on the array as it is. If you want to keep the O(log n) property of the solution you have to impelemnt your own binary search. If you modify the array (in place or in a copy) and subtract i from a[i], you can then use bsearch(). The complexity for doing so is O(n).