# Search in sorted array X for first index i such that X[i] >= a

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, language-agnostic

I'm struggling to adapt the code found by codaddict [proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172580/interview-question-search-in-sorted-array-x-for-index-i-such-that-xi-i) to solve 
this simple variant of the problem. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: What are you struggling with?

Comment: Should we just post the code or?

Comment: I'm no computer scientist, but how do you modify codaddict's code (maybe its a standard step). I mean, i can't change if(X[mid] - mid == 0) to if(X[mid] - mid > 0) otherwise the algorithm always returns mid :(

Comment: In what language do you want the solution?

Comment: c++ (or eventually either one of JAVA\R\matlab). The language doesn't really matter, i specially want to understand the logic (again sorry if it's an embarrassingly simple question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You take his algorithm, and return `high` instead of `-1`. If `X[high]` is smaller than your target, take the next item instead. If `high` is equal to your array size, there is no such index.

Michael Anderson is right about how the algorithm you pointed to was written, but it is easy to adapt.

```
int find_hi (const std::vector<int> &X, int t) {
   int low  = 0;
   int high = X.size() - 1;
   while(low <= high) {
       int mid = (low + high) / 2;
       if(X[mid] == t) return mid;
       else if(X[mid] < t)
           low = mid + 1;
       else
           high = mid - 1;
   }
   if (high < sz && X[high] < t) ++high;
   return high;
}
```

However, this is equivalent to the following in C++:

```
int find_hi (const std::vector<int> &X, int t) {
    return std::lower_bound(X.begin(), X.end(), t) - X.begin();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an adoptation of [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

int arr[9]={0,1,2,3,4,5,7,7,8};

/*int * array - where to search
  int numberOfElements - the number of elements in array
  int targetValue - the value that we are looking for 
*/

int find( int * array, int numberOfElements, int targetValue)
{
    //we start with searching in the whole array (this is our "scope").
    int left = 0;
    int right = numberOfElements;

    while(left < right)
    {
        //We take the middle item of our "scope" and compare it with the target value.
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        if( array[ mid ] >= targetValue)//If we did hit
        {
            //we check is it the first item to match our criteria.              
            if(array[ mid - 1 ] < targetValue)
            {
                //If it is, we return the index.
                return mid;
            }
            else
            { 
                //Else, we continue searching to the left. 
                right = mid;
            }
        }
        //If we didnt hit from the first guess, we continue with our "scope"
        //being either the left of the right half of the previous "scope".
        else if( array[mid] > targetValue )
            right = mid;
        else
            left = mid;
     }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << find(arr, 9, 7);
}
```

`output: 3`

Answer (score 1):

To find the first index `i` where `X[i] >= a` you need to modify the end condition like this to check if it really is the first index to satisfy the condition:

```
public int findIndex(int[] array, int target) {
    int left = 0;
    int right = array.length;
    while (left < right) {
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        if (array[mid] >= target && (mid == 0 || array[mid - 1] < target)) {
            return mid;
        } else if (array[mid] > target) {
            right = mid;
        } else
            left = mid;
    }
    return -1;
}
```