# Search a sorted integer array for an element equal to its index, where A may have duplicate entries

Tags: algorithm, search

My question is very similar to [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632801/what-would-be-the-most-efficient-way-to-find-ai-i-in-a-sorted-array?lq=1) and [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172580/interview-question-search-in-sorted-array-x-for-index-i-such-that-xi-i), except that I want to deal with the case where the array may have duplicate entries.

Assume the array A consists of integers sorted in increasing order. If its entries are all distinct, you can do this easily in O(log n) with binary search. But if there are duplicate entries, it's more complicated. Here's my approach:

```
int search(const vector<int>& A) {
    int left = 0, right = A.size() - 1;
    return binarySearchHelper(A, left, right);
}

int binarySearchHelper(const vector<int>& A, int left, int right) {
    int indexFound = -1;
    if (left <= right) {
        int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
        if (A[mid] == mid) {
            return mid;
        } else {
            if (A[mid] <= right) {
                indexFound = binarySearchHelper(A, mid + 1, right);
            }
            if (indexFound == -1 && A[left] <= mid) {
                indexFound = binarySearchHelper(A, left, mid - 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return indexFound;    
}
```

In the worst case (A has no element equal to its index), `binarySearchHelper` makes 2 recursive calls with input size halved at each level of recursion, meaning it has a worst-case time complexity of O(n). That's the same as the O(n) approach where you just read through the array in order. Is this really the best you can do? Also, is there a way to measure the algorithm's average time complexity? If not, is there some heuristic for deciding when to use the basic O(n) read-through approach and when to try a recursive approach such as mine?

If A has negative integers, then it's necessary to check the condition `if (left <= right)` in `binarySearchHelper`. Since, for example, if `A = [-1]`, then the algorithm would recurse from `bsh(A, 0, 0)` to `bsh(A,1,0)` and to `bsh(A,0,-1)`. My intuition leads me to believe **the check `if (left <= right)` is necessary if and only if A has some negative integers.** Can anyone help me verify this?

Comment: EDIT: someone deleted their comment asking why the existence of duplicate entries matter. Consider `A = [1,2,2]`. The plain vanilla binary search would see that `A[1] > 1` and decide to only look at the bottom half. Now consider `A = [0,0,1]`. The plain vanilla binary search would see that `A[1] < 1` and decide to only look at the bottom half.

Comment: How is this related to Java?

Comment: @luk32: it's not. I removed the tag.

Comment: I have a hunch that this can't be done in better than linear time. Searching for `A[i]==i` is equivalent to searching for zero in an array `B` such that `B[i] == A[i]-i`, and `B` is not sorted if `A` has duplicates. I haven't come up with the formal proof off the top of my head though.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: That's a good informal reasoning. Lets say you're told there are at most `k` duplicates, with `k << n`, then is the linear approach still optimal? Or would that allow for a divide-and-conquer approach where you can constrain the average time complexity to faster than O(n)?

Comment: Suppose the integers in the array are drawn uniformly from `Z_m = {0, 1, ..., m-1}`. As a function of m and n, how many duplicates should you expect? Is there a relationship between the number of expected duplicates and the average-case time complexity of the modified binary search algorithm? If so, when if ever is it expected to out-perform the linear approach in the average case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a different approach. First I would eliminate all negative numbers in **O(log n)** simply by doing a binary search for the first positive number. This is allowed because no negative number can be equal to its index. Let's say the index of the first positive element is `i`.

Now I will keep doing the following until I find the element or find that it doesn't exist:

1. If `i` not inside `A`, return false.
2. If `i < A[i]` do `i = A[i]`. It would take `A[i] - i` duplicates to have `i` 'catch up' to `A[i]`, so we would increment `i` by `A[i] - i`, this is equivalent to setting `i` to `A[i]`. Go to 1.
3. If `i == A[i]` return true (and index if you want to).
4. Find the first index greater than `i` such that `i <= A[i]`. You can do this doing a 'binary search from the left' by incrementing `i` by 1, 2, 4, 8, etc and then doing a binary search on the last interval you found it in. If it doesn't exist, return false.

In the worst case the above is stil **O(n)**, but it has many tricks to speed it up way beyond that in better cases.

Comment: Consider A=[-100, -99, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9].  We arrive at step 1 with i=2.  i = 2 > A[i] = 1, so we pass over steps 2 and 3.  In step 4, we try to use binary search to find the first j <= A[j] by setting j to 2+1, 2+2, 2+4, and 2+8, but for each of those, j > A[j], even though we've passed by A[5] and A[9].